# Simple Binary Tree question about a custom insert function

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-tree

I'm working on a program to build a binary tree and it works, but I'm curious as to something:

When I don't assign the recursion of `insertNode` to `node.leftChild` or `node.rightChild`, the tree is made with only the root added, no other values, while when I do assign `insertNode` to `node.rightChild`, it inserts the desired array fully into a binary tree. What I mean is, when I replace lines 33 and 35 of my code with just `insertNode(node.leftChild, key);` and `insertNode(node.rightChild, key);` it only inserts the root (first array item) into a tree and nothing else. Why is this?

I attached a screenshot of the code with an embedded link
[image]

Comment: Don't post a screenshot of your code. Post the code as part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

> When I don't assign the recursion of `insertNode` to `node.leftChild` or `node.rightChild`, the tree is made with only the root added, no other values

This is expected, since it is the *only place* where a value is assigned to either a `leftChild` or `rightChild` property. So if it doesn't happen there, it doesn't happen at all. And so it becomes impossible that the root would get a left or right child.

> when I do assign `insertNode` to `node.rightChild`, it inserts the desired array fully into a binary tree.

Yes, the idea behind this algorithm is that when the insertion spot is found, the recursion stops (base case). At that moment (alone) the new node is created. But this node remains unattached to the rest of the tree. The idea here is that the *caller* of the recursive function is responsible for attaching that new node to the node that should be its parent. So when the ne node is created, it is *returned* without any further action. The *caller* will then assign that new node to `node.rightChild` or `node.leftChild`. At that moment the tree is ready.

Still, the process will continue to get out of the recursion tree, each time returning `node` to the caller. In all these remaining cases that means the caller will assign the returned node to a property that *already had the same node reference there*. But this is of course not a problem.

This assignment is really only relevant when the caller is making the call with a `null` reference for the first argument. In that case it will get a non-null reference back, which it has to assign properly to add that new node to the tree. If, on the other hand, the recursive call is made with a non-null node reference, then the return value will be *that* reference.